# Resolved issue between no commited same local system and git file

Tags: git, git-commit, merge-conflict-resolution, mergetool

In one of git scenario, I have same not commit file on local system which is available on git Server as well. Now situation is, I haven't add these local system file and after stashing when I'm trying to pull master it prompt **error** to delete these local files.

Any suggestion how to fix this.

Comment: You try to add the local file in .gitignore,  its not a legal advice

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you on your `develop` branch and your desired local file is `experimental.local.file.txt`. In this case you can use this scheme:

1. Create experimental branch `git checkout -b experimental`
2. Add this local file to git `git add experimental.local.file.txt`
3. Commit it `git commit -m 'Add experimental file'`
4. Get remote branch (i.e `origin/develop`) and merge it with this experimental one `git pull ./ origin/develop`
5. Resolve conflicts and commit it
6. Checkout back to `develop` with command `git checkout develop`
7. Now you can just merge your `develop` branch with `origin/develop` with command `git pull`. There are no more `experimental.local.file.txt` in your local branch, so your can pull without errors.
8. Then checkout your `experimental.local.file.txt` file from `experimental` branch with command below:
9. `git checkout experimental path/to/experimental.local.file.txt`